# Can I attach a texture, which I created, to a QOpenGLFramebufferObject?

Tags: qt, opengl, fbo

QOpenGLFramebufferObject provides methods that internally create a texture and attach it to the FBO. But what if I have an existing texture ID (taken from a QSGTexture btw) and I want to attach it to the FBO?

Comment: Why not to try and tell us if it worked.SO is the place to help you to solve the problem,not to solve it for you.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov: How can I try when I don't know what function/class to use? I did look at the QOFBO docs and I didn't find anything that does what I ask for in the question. That doesn't mean I didn't miss something though.

Comment: I don't like Qt's gl wrappers design. I use raw GL in my Qt apps.If you can't find a method to attach a texture to their fbo wrapper, then maybe you should try creating fbo from scratch?

Comment: @MichaelIvanov: Already did so and it works fine, but if someone provides a working answer to my question, I may switch back to the qt wrapper, for many reasons.

Comment: I have just inspected the docs and indeed can't see any method to pass in an external texture. As I said, Qt's  GL wrappers suck; )